# What affects the sale price of a vehicle in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I've noticed that if I've modified one of my (non-premium) vehicles then the price at which I can sell it for goes up. For example, I have an Ocelot F620 which has a normal sale price of $8000. I have since added a few mods to it (improved engine tuning, etc.) and now if I try to sell it the price offered is around $13000. (I can't remember exactly how much I've spend on the mods -- it was over a period of several weeks.)

So I was just wondering if anyone has ever bothered to work this out? If for example I spend $1000 on mods, how much does the price increase by? (it it that simple?) Are there any mods that don't increase the price? (like respraying?) Also, if I buy two mods in the same category (for example 'Engine Tuning 1' and 'Engine Tuning 2') does it just increase the price due to the more expensive of the two, or does it increase by some combination of the two?

I've tried briefly to figure this out myself, but the sale price of the car seems to behave in a strange way. I can drive my car into Los Santos Customs and check the sale price (by selecting 'sell', but not actually proceeding with the sale). If I then modify the car in some way, then check the sale price again, the sale price is unchanged! However, if I check the sale price of the car a day or so later (real-world time) the sale price has gone up to reflect the new modification. So I guess that leads on to another question: How long do you have to wait before car mods have an influence on the sale price?

Comment: as for your last paragraph, did you leave the garage and re-enter before checking the price again?  The changes might not have applied until you exited the garage, thus the sell price remained the same until the next time you visited LSC.

Comment: Yes, I believe I exited LSC and re-entered -- no difference. I took my car back to my garage and then back to LSC -- no difference. The only think I didn't do was try to enter a different session, or log out and back into GTA online.

Comment: @turbo: so are you saying that the price is updating for you if you leave/enter LSC straight away? Perhaps I need to do some more investigating...

Comment: No, I don't have any experience upgrading and selling cars. I was just throwing it out there as something to try.  If it worked, then you could continue to investigate.  Changing sessions might do it, but I would recommend setting your spawn to last the location rather than your apartment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a bit of investigation I can answer (at least part of) my own question.

First, it seems that my initial recollection of the price given by LSC was wrong: you *can* indeed check the price of a car, add a modification, drive out, drive back in again and check the newly updated price (obviously this is only possible if you have not sold a car in the last 48 mins -- otherwise you will be told that they are not accepting any vehicles at the moment).

Here is what I have figured out so far:

- After a modification, the price added to the sale price is exactly 50% of the cost of the modification.
- Modifying the car with multiple items from the same category does not increase the sale price by the sum of all those modifications. For example, if you already have 'Engine Tuning 2' and you then fit 'Engine Tuning 1', the latter will **REPLACE** the former and the sale price will **DROP** by 50% of the difference between cost of the two mods.
- Most of the modifications I've tried so far **DO** add to the sale price of the car. However, there may be some that don't (as I have not extensively tried all of them). I will update if I find any that do not.

Comment: I've also been looking into this situation. But when I add mods to my car I see an increase of the sale price without having to leave LSC. Also, I've not tested enough to say what causes some to increase value while others don't,but certain paint jobs&rim typesdo add value while others don't.I know getting bulletproof tires&any performance related mods (engine,transmission,turbo etc.) increase value,as does armor. As you've noted yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The mods that affect sale price are anything affecting performance and anything that adds options to your car.  So armor, breaks, trans, engine, hoods, spoilers, bumpers, wheels, horn.  You can buy bulletproof tires to change the price but that's it.

Mods that DON'T effect sale price are respray colors, license plate, windows, tire smoke, custom tire accessory (atomic), underglow.  And xenon headlights don't give 50%, it's more like 20% for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

You get 50% back on what you have originally purchased, but if you are trying to flip cars, adding mods loses you money.

Comment: Your not really adding anything new that was not already covered in the accepted answer..