# Does the sell price increase when the sale ends?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I bought T20 on sale for 1.650 million. The sell price is now 1.05 million. My question is, will the sell price go up when the sale ends?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a [great answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/141646/158613)  by ltn100 on how the sell price is roughly calculated.

> Here is what I have figured out so far:
>
> After a modification, the price added to the sale price is exactly 50% of the cost of the modification.
>
> Modifying the car with multiple items from the same category does not
> increase the sale price by the sum of all those modifications. For example, if you already have 'Engine Tuning 2' and you then fit 'Engine Tuning 1', the latter will REPLACE the former and the sale price will DROP by 50% of the difference between cost of the two mods.
>
> Most of the modifications I've tried so far DO add to the sale price of the car. However, there may be some that don't (as I have not extensively tried all of them). I will update if I find any that do not.

The only variable that's affected by the sell price is the modification you install on your vehicle. The price you originally bought the car for does not seem to affect it.